# Re-using observables for in-flight API requests

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a component A that queries the API on its own and stores results in cache using RX:

```
List<Data> cache = ...;

void queryData(int parameter) {
    myApi.getData(parameter).subscribe(data => cache.add(data));
}
```

Now, I would like to query this cache from other components. On a cache miss, I would like the design to allow re-using an in-flight subscription if it exists. This is to avoid duplicating an identical request.

I am thinking of storing the `Observable` in a separate cache (still in my component A).

```
List<Observable<Data>> requestCache = ...;

public Observable<Data> getData(int parameter) {
    // if cache contains data, return new observable that emits that item

    // if cache does not contain data, check if requestCache contains the Observable I need. If so, return it.

    // if all else fails, return queryData(parameter)

}
```

and I would need to modify my original `queryData` to be something like:

```
Observable<Data> queryData(int parameter) {
    Observable<Data> observable = myApi.getData(parameter);

    requestCache.add(observable);

    observable.subscribe(data => cache.add(data));
    observable.subscribe(data => requestCache.remove(observable));

    return observable;
}
```

This would completely hide the caching/in flight complexity of these requests to other components. However, I wonder if there's a built-in way in RX to handle this.

Am I on the right track or is there a better pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way of doing this. Here is how I would solve this problem:

```
public final class ReactiveCache<K, V> {
    final Map<K, Observable<V>> requests = new HashMap<>();

    final Function<K, Observable<V>> generator;

    public ReactiveCache(Function<K, Observable<V>> generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    public Observable<V> get(K key) {
        ConnectableObservable<V> result;
        synchronized (requests) {
            Observable<V> current = requests.get(key);
            if (current != null) {
                return current;
            }

            result = generator.apply(key)
                    .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                        synchronized (requests) {
                            requests.remove(key);
                        }
                    })
                    .replay();

            requests.put(key, result);
        }

        return result.autoConnect(0);
    }
}
```

In this class, when you call get() and there is an in-flight observable, you can join it and receive all of its values. If there is none or the in-flight has finished, you'll start a new Observable.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. If I understand correctly, this does not cache data indefinitely. If I want to keep all downloaded data around, anything else to consider but adding a `.subscribe()` to `.replay()` (which would store the result in a separate Map<K, V>)?

Comment: So do you want to avoid multiple requests with the same key and have access to results indefinitely and never clear the cache? Your first attempt didn't look like you wanted this.

Comment: Yes, actually. Maybe I should revise my post to make it clearer. There's the public `getData()` method that queries from both caches and the private `queryData()` who manages the request (observable) cache only. If that makes sense.

Comment: In that case, just remove the `doOnTerminate` operator and the cache will hold and replay the value indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on a satisfying path.

Comment: Is there any sample code that demonstrates how to use such ReactiveCache?

Comment: @akarnokd is there maybe a better way to do this now? e.g.  newer operators, or some extension lib you know of?

Comment: @TmTron the pattern is still the same today. I don't know any specific library that does this.